# Extract data from list of lists? [Python 3.8]

Tags: python, mysql, list

Say I have this `listoflists`:

```
for sub_list in listoflists:
print(sub_list)
```

Output:

```
[('id', '1'), ('id', '2'), ('id', '3'), ('id', '4'), ('id', '5'), ('id', '6'), ('id', '7')]
[('username', 'admin'), ('username', 'boss'), ('username', 'bubu'), ('username', 'david'), ('username', 'leet'), ('username', 'niki'), ('username', 'roman')]
[('password', '!QAZ@WSX#EDC'), ('password', '!QAZ@WSX#EDC123123'), ('password', '123123'), ('password', '123456Aa!'), ('password', '1337'), ('password', 'A123456a'), ('password', 'QAZWSXEDC!')]
[('role', 'admin'), ('role', 'admin'), ('role', 'nobody'), ('role', 'user'), ('role', 'user'), ('role', 'user'), ('role', 'user')]
```

How can I sort all the data out to eventually make a table with columns: id, username, password, role?
Using `prettytables` or whatever is the best and most pythonic way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use use `pandas` to create dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    [('id', '1'), ('id', '2'), ('id', '3'), ('id', '4'), ('id', '5'), ('id', '6'), ('id', '7')],
    [('username', 'admin'), ('username', 'boss'), ('username', 'bubu'), ('username', 'david'), ('username', 'leet'), ('username', 'niki'), ('username', 'roman')],
    [('password', '!QAZ@WSX#EDC'), ('password', '!QAZ@WSX#EDC123123'), ('password', '123123'), ('password', '123456Aa!'), ('password', '1337'), ('password', 'A123456a'), ('password', 'QAZWSXEDC!')],
    [('role', 'admin'), ('role', 'admin'), ('role', 'nobody'), ('role', 'user'), ('role', 'user'), ('role', 'user'), ('role', 'user')],
]

df = pd.DataFrame([dict(subl) for subl in zip(*data)])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  id username            password    role
0  1    admin        !QAZ@WSX#EDC   admin
1  2     boss  !QAZ@WSX#EDC123123   admin
2  3     bubu              123123  nobody
3  4    david           123456Aa!    user
4  5     leet                1337    user
5  6     niki            A123456a    user
6  7    roman          QAZWSXEDC!    user
```

---

Or: Just use plain Python:

```
print('{:<10} {:<20} {:<20} {}'.format('id', 'username', 'password', 'role'))

for d in zip(*data):
    print('{:<10} {:<20} {:<20} {}'.format(*[v for _, v in d]))
```

Prints:

```
id         username             password             role
1          admin                !QAZ@WSX#EDC         admin
2          boss                 !QAZ@WSX#EDC123123   admin
3          bubu                 123123               nobody
4          david                123456Aa!            user
5          leet                 1337                 user
6          niki                 A123456a             user
7          roman                QAZWSXEDC!           user
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir!
say for example the listsoflists changes (more\less columns, different data, etc...)  (as it should in my program depending on user inputs) i should use the panda method right?
because plain python only works for this list specifically, and panda will sort everything no matter the data and\or no. of columns

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

all_lists = [
  [('id', '1'), ('id', '2'), ('id', '3'), ('id', '4'), ('id', '5'), ('id', '6'), ('id', '7')], 
  [('username', 'admin'), ('username', 'boss'), ('username', 'bubu'), ('username', 'david'), ('username', 'leet'), ('username', 'niki'), ('username', 'roman')],
  [('password', '!QAZ@WSX#EDC'), ('password', '!QAZ@WSX#EDC123123'), ('password', '123123'), ('password', '123456Aa!'), ('password', '1337'), ('password', 'A123456a'), ('password', 'QAZWSXEDC!')],
  [('role', 'admin'), ('role', 'admin'), ('role', 'nobody'), ('role', 'user'), ('role', 'user'), ('role', 'user'), ('role', 'user')]
]

cols = [l[0][0] for l in all_lists]
data = [[tup[1] for tup in l] for l in all_lists]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols, data=zip(*data))
print(df)
```

```
  id username            password    role
0  1    admin        !QAZ@WSX#EDC   admin
1  2     boss  !QAZ@WSX#EDC123123   admin
2  3     bubu              123123  nobody
3  4    david           123456Aa!    user
4  5     leet                1337    user
5  6     niki            A123456a    user
6  7    roman          QAZWSXEDC!    user
```